# Different colors for data values in MigraDoc chart

Tags: c#, .net, migradoc

I have the following chart which I create with MigraDoc within my C# application:

```
Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.Bar2D);
chart.Width = "10cm";
chart.Height = "10cm";
Series series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
series.Add(new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 });
XSeries xseries = chart.XValues.AddXSeries();
xseries.Add("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
chart.XAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
chart.XAxis.Title.Caption = "X-Axis";
chart.YAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
chart.YAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Color = Colors.AliceBlue;
chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Width = 1;
chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Visible = true;
MigraDocObject.Add(chart);
```

Now lets say I want to be bar A in `Colors.AliceBlue` and bar B in `Colors.DarkGray`. How can I accomplish that? Is it possible via the official API? Or do I have to hack MigraDoc?

Answer (score 6):

my solution:

```
Series series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
series.Add(new double[] { 3, 10, 10, 150, 7, 192, 6 });
var elements = series.Elements.Cast<MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Charts.Point>().ToArray();
elements[0].FillFormat.Color = Colors.Chartreuse;
elements[3].FillFormat.Color = Colors.DeepSkyBlue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to have a different series for each bar you want to color differently. You would have to hack around a bit with your values and pretty much overlay all your bars.

```
Series seriesA = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
seriesA.Add(new double[] { 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
seriesA.FillFormat.Color = Colors.AliceBlue;

Series seriesB = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
seriesB.Add(new double[] { 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
seriesB.FillFormat.Color = Colors.DarkGray;

Series seriesC = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
seriesC.Add(new double[] { 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
seriesC.FillFormat.Color = Colors.Red;
```

Just make sure that each new series references your same chart object.  And if you can help it, make sure to turn your series.HasDataLabel = false so that you don't have your series values overlaying each other.

Depending on the size and complexity of chart, this should be easy enough to copy/paste your way through it.